# Add Information / Details to a TableView row

Tags: swift, segue, viewcontroller

I have a TableView with items on the first ViewController. When I click on a row i perform a segue to display a second ViewController with a TextField on it.
Now i want to write Informations to the TextField and link that information to the selected row from the first ViewController. So that Information1 is shown when you click row1 and Information2 is shown when you click row2 and so on.
I dont want to have as many ViewControllers as Items, so Im wondering what the best way would be to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need only 1 vc as the destination of segue with a variable that you set from `prepare` method

```
let arr = [YourModel(name:"ppp",age:11),YourModel(name:"ppp",age:14)]
```

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegue", sender: arr[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourSegue" {
        let des = segue.destination as! DetailVC
        des.item = sender as! YourModel

    } 
}
```

---

```
struct YourModel {
    let name: String
    let age: Int 
}
```

---

```
class DetailVC:UIViewController { 
   var item:YourModel?
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what "item" is in the line `des.item = sender as! YourModel` ?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Maybe i was not clear enough, because i want to show information entered by the user into the TextView, not given infos by an array. But i have the basics now from you guys and I will have a closer look by myself now first. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

declare a global `public var content:String?` in your destination View Controller

in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` of your parentViewController, write this before performing segue:

```
let destVC = YourDestinationVC()
destVC.content = "content pertaining to cell selected"

// if the segue name is called segueOne
destinationVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueOne", sender: self)
```

This will perform the segue with preloaded Data

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question is more about how to design your app so as its easy to maintain. Here is my suggestion:

```
//1. Create a structure to hold the data
struct Information{
    let cellTitle : String
    let messageToDisplay : String

    init(cellTitle: String, messageToDisplay: String){
        self.cellTitle = cellTitle
        self.messageToDisplay = messageToDisplay
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    //2. Create a datasource array
    let datasource : [Information] = [Information(cellTitle: "Cell1", messageToDisplay: "Message To Display on for Cell1"),
                                    Information(cellTitle: "Cell2", messageToDisplay: "Message To Display on for Cell2"),
                                    Information(cellTitle: "Cell3", messageToDisplay: "Message To Display on for Cell3")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowSecondViewController", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

        if segue.identifier == "ShowSecondViewController" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            //3.0 Create a variable in your destination Viewcontroller and set it here
            vc.messageToShow = datasource[(indexPath?.row)!].messageToDisplay

        }
    }
}
```